# Cannot modify array by slicing in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unpack

I have this external definition that wraps up a buffer and functions that perform operations on that buffer.

```
var Packer = {
    _buffer: new Buffer(""),

    readShort: function(){
        var rs = this._buffer.readInt16BE();
        console.log('first buffer len ' + this._buffer.length);
        this._buffer = this._buffer.slice(2);
        console.log('second buffer len ' + this._buffer.length);
        return rs;
    },

    readString: function(){
        var len = this.readShort();
        console.log('while reading string len is ' + len);
        var rs = this._buffer.toString('utf8', 2, len + 2);
        this._buffer = this._buffer.slice(len + 2);
        return rs;
    },
};

exports.Packer = Packer;
```

Externally, I call the following:

```
var HelloBob = {
    handlePacket: function(p){
         //.. p is a string
         p = new Buffer(p);

         var packer = Object.spawn(pack.Packer, {_buffer: p});

         //Bob is trying to improve his knowledge
         var humansOnMoon = packer.readShort();
         var nameOfGalaxy = packer.readString();
    },
};
```

The problem is that the buffer does not update after the readShort operation (which implies a slice that cuts out a part of the buffer).

```
first buffer len 354
second buffer len 354
while reading string len is 354
```

I read that the buffer resulting after the slice memory shares memory with the original buffer. I have also attempted to copy the buffer (overlap it) to remove the first (2) elements but it behaves identically.

**Why is this happening and how can I solve it?**

Notes:

- p is a buffer of length 354
- [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

Comment: The code slicing the array should work just fine, something else is going on? You're probably accessing the same array both times, either because it hasn't changed *yet*, or because you've done something wrong. It should be noted that you don't return the modified buffer, but the result of `readInt16BE()`?

Comment: @adeneo Indeed, I'm returning the value I read from the Buffer. The purpose is to call the read again on the same buffer but to read the following value not the same one (that's why I am slicing the buffer)

Comment: I think you'll have to post how you're calling the functions, and what `Object.spawn` does etc.

Comment: @adeneo The value of length is not subject to a change even between the two logs in the readShort function.

Comment: Did you try calling `toString` on the buffers, to see if that changes, it could be an issue with logging live "objects" (buffers)

Comment: @adeneo I did. Same result unfortunately.

Comment: That's strange, buffers should be Uint8Arrays, and they do have a `slice` method that should work -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lnuxhfm2/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by setting the _buffer variable through a function (not through the initializer). Somehow, it behaves as if it was immutable if I set it in the {}.

```
var packer = Object.spawn(pack.Packer, {});
packer.setBuffer(new Buffer(p));
```

Added this setter:

```
setBuffer: function(nbf){
    this._buffer = nbf;
}
```

Comment: Sounds more like a scope issue, where `this` is not what you think it is, and the value of `this` depends on the execution context, so in other words it all depends on how the `Object.spawn` function works